# While installing npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled, I'm getting ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependence tree

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
is not working. Please help me out. [error detail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt2Tw.png)

I tried installing npm install @mui/material only, too. But, it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying `npm` found `React 16.14.0` but that `@mui/material@5.11.0` wants *React 17 or 18*.

You can either use [Material-UI v4](https://v4.mui.com/getting-started/installation/) or upgrade your version of React.